# Concrete Example of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am not sure if I understand the $\inf$ meanings in Fatou's Lemma. The assertion states that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X \inf f_n d\mu \leq \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{X}  f_n d\mu$$

I would like to understand its meaning and see the use of the lemma through a simple example. So let the sequence of functions be $f_n(x) =  \big(1 + \frac{1}{n} \big)^n x$ for $n \geq 1$, where $n \in  \mathbb{N}$.

Obviously it is an increasing sequence that converges to $f(x) = e x$. Let us integrate over the $[0,1]$ interval. My questions are:

1. For the left hand side of the inequality we would need to integrate $\inf f_n$ and then evaluate its limit. This function would in our case be given by $x$ right?. If true, then the value of the integal is simply $\frac{1}{2}$. What do we do with the limit then?
2. And for the right hand side we have to evaluate $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} \big(1 + \frac{1}{n} \big)^n$. The smaller value $\forall n \geq 1$ is $1$. Again, what is the use of the limit here?

Thanks!

Comment: Fatou's lemma is actually the stronger assertion that $\int_X \liminf_n f_n d \mu \leq \liminf_n \int_X f_n d \mu$.

Comment: I hope you're not confusing the definition of $\liminf$ (the limit inferior), which is what Fatou's lemma talks about. By (one of several equivalent) definition, if $\{a_n\}$ is any sequence of numbers in $[-\infty,\infty]$, we define $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf\limits_{k\geq n}a_k\right)$. It does NOT mean $\lim\left(\inf\limits_{n\geq 1}a_n\right)$, because then the $\lim$ does nothing because we're taking the limit of the constant sequence $\inf\limits_{n\geq 1}a_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. And @peek-a-boo, so in this example after evaluating the limit inferiors we would actually be left with $\frac{e}{2} \leq \frac{e}{2}$, right?

Comment: yes exactly (in fact if you want to use a hammer, you can see that dominated convergence theorem holds, so indeed the fact that the two quantities are equal makes perfect sense). If you want to get a better feel for this, try some other examples, and try to construct an example where strict inequality holds.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: TeX hint: there is a built-in `\liminf` to use for the $\liminf$.  Then the affix below it comes out right: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have pointed out in the comments, you are confusing $\liminf$ and the infimum notation. For a concrete example of strict inequality, consider $f_n = n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Could you give me a hint of what $ \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n$ looks like in your example? Graphing the function for many values of $n$ I have noticed that as $n \to \infty$ the function converges to the point $(0,\infty)$, and when $n \to 0$ $f_n$ goes to the nonnegative x axis.

Comment: Can you show that the function converges *pointwise* to $f\equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$? If you can show that, then $\liminf f_n = \lim f_n \equiv 0$.